# Get `li` elements and push it into object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple question!

I have this `html` and `js`:

```
<ul>
  <li id="x">foo</li>
  <li id="y">bar</li>
</ul>

var data = {
  'language': 'fa',
  'phrases': {},
};
```

I want to append all `li` in the `phrases` of `data` for have this output:

```
{"language":"fa","phrases":{"x":"foo","y":"bar"}}
```

I try this:

```
data.phrases.$(this).attr('id') = $(this).html();
```

And try `push` this:

```
data.phrases.push( {$(this).attr('id') : $(this).html()} );
```

And try `extend` this:

```
data.phrases.extend( {$(this).attr('id') : $(this).html()} );
```

But does not work!

Completed code:

```
<ul>
  <li id="x">foo</li>
  <li id="y">bar</li>
</ul>

<div id="result"></div>

var data = {
  'language': 'fa',
  'phrases': {},
};

//I want to append all `li` in the `phrases` of `data` for have this output:
//{"language":"fa","phrases":{"x":"foo","y":"bar"}}
$("li").each(function() {
  //data.phrases.$(this).attr('id') = $(this).html();
  //data.phrases.push( {$(this).attr('id') : $(this).html()} );
  //data.phrases.extend( {$(this).attr('id') : $(this).html()} );
});

$("#result").html(JSON.stringify( data ));
```

See here online code: https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/fw63jd5k/

Comment: try this =>
data["phrases"][$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).html();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close! The issue is that the dot operator in JavaScript cannot be used to evaluate a key then access it. You're looking for the [ ] operator, which can be used to evaluate whatever is in the brackets, then use the value as the key. So try this:

```
data.phrases[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).html();
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot `.push()` into Object.
Use assignment to properties instead:

```js
var data = {
  'language': 'fa',
  'phrases': {},
};

$("li").text(function(i, txt) {
  data.phrases[this.id] = txt;
});

$("#result").html(JSON.stringify( data ));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="x">foo</li>
  <li id="y">bar</li>
</ul>

<div id="result"></div>
```

> `data.phrases`      is your object literal
>     `[this.id]` is your new object property, where `this.id` is the current `li`'s ID
>     `= txt;`     is where you assign to that property the value of the current `li` text

As you can figure out from above, if you need the entire HTML use `.html()` instead like:

```
$("li").html(function(i, html) {
  data.phrases[this.id] = html;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, `text()` and `html()` is good idea, but I must use `each()` because I need to find by `data` attribute and then use `each` on it, and  use `data` attribute of `$(this)` element for index array... But use `data.phrases[id]=val` is my answer.

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. **You don't have to use .each** as you can see by simply clicking the [Run code snippet] button on my answer. Both `.text()` and `.html()` provide a callback just like `.each()` - again - clearly visible from my example. See how I used `this.id` ? Rings any bells? You can use `$(this).attr("id")` or `$(this).whateverYouWant()`.

Comment: You said currently, the `html()` is be like `each()` and that's clearly and simpler. But why you tell the faster and performance?!

Answer (score 1):

you have the right idea, but you aren't quite using your functions correctly. push is an array method, and extend just isn't a native method. so what we want to do is set the id to the key, and the value to the html

https://jsfiddle.net/fw63jd5k/2/

```
$("li").each(function(i, el) {
  data.phrases[el.id] = $(el).html()
}
```